# Indy SNMP QuickSend failed

Tags: delphi, snmp, indy

this is my code use QuickSend method to get sysDesc is OK but with Symbol Rate it always fail. I don't know, the same code actually works in another project I wrote before (I run it again and everything is fine).

```
     var
    mySNMP: TidSNMP;
    SymbolRate, sysDesc: string;

   begin
     mySNMP:=TidSNMP.Create(nil);
     try
      mySNMP.Host:=Trim(IpEdit.Text);
      mySNMP.Community:=Trim(CommEdit.Text);
      mySNMP.ReceiveTimeout:=1000;
      if mySNMP.QuickSend('1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0', mySNMP.Community, mySNMP.Host, sysDesc)
        then
        ShowMessage(sysDesc)
        else
        ShowMessage('Send Failed');
      if mySNMP.QuickSend('.1.3.6.1.4.1.6247.24.1.2.2.12.0',mySNMP.Community, mySNMP.Host,SymbolRate)
        then
        ShowMessage('Send OK')
        else
        ShowMessage('Send Failed');
     finally
      mySNMP.Free;
     end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QuickSend()` (and `SendQuery()` in general) returns False if:

1. the socket is reset (it reports error code 10054, `WSAECONNRESET`).
2. no response is received within the specified timeout.
3. the response cannot be parsed.
4. the response is parsed by contains an error code from the server (see the `Reply.ErrorStatus` property).

The first thing I would suggest is for you to remove the leading `.` from the failing OID:

```
if mySNMP.QuickSend('1.3.6.1.4.1.6247.24.1.2.2.12.0',mySNMP.Community, mySNMP.Host,SymbolRate)
```

That way, it matches the query code in your [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23010142/snmp-method-to-set-objects-value), which was working:

```
SNMP.QuickSend('1.3.6.1.4.1.6247.24.1.2.2.12.0',SNMP.Community,SNMP.Host,SRate);
```

Comment: I think this because I put the OID in a constant string "IDSymbolRate" and I thought it was correct due to copy from MIB Browser. If I didn't rewrite directly the OID, it will be more difficult to detect the error.